# Two different version of sbt version

Tags: scala, sbt

My sbt versions are different! Just like below..

C:\Users\username>sbt --version
sbt version in this project: 1.3.13
sbt script version: 1.9.4

Is it okay to execute programs? I need your help.

I have an error about using sbt

Error just like this! (below)

sbt:scalatutorial> test

[info] Updating

[info] Resolved  dependencies

[warn]

[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:

[error] stack trace is suppressed; run last macros / update for the full output

[error] (macros / update) sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: Error downloading org.wartremover:wartremover_2.13.11:3.0.6

[error]   Not found

[error]   Not found

[error]   not found: C:\Users\SonHyeonJin.ivy2\localorg.wartremover\wartremover_2.13.11\3.0.6\ivys\ivy.xml

[error]   not found: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/wartremover/wartremover_2.13.11/3.0.6/wartremover_2.13.11-3.0.6.pom

[error] Total time: 4 s, completed 2023. 8. 31. ?ㅽ썑 12:25:55

Comment: And what would the error be?

Comment: And what do you have in project's `project/build.properties`?

Comment: Actually, I have to do my project(name to be scala-tutorial), but

Answer (score 4):

This is expected: the SBT tool installed on your machine (1.9.4) can work with project "managed" by another SBT version (1.3.13 in your case, it's declared on the `build.properties` file of the project).

To do so, SBT will auto download itself in the version needed by the project (1.3.13)

This should work fine. Nothing to worry about. I'd still recommend to upgrade the version of the project though.